# JavaScript in HTML: Response to Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on the meat in my page, and I've got the Javascript function for a list of two radio buttons pretty much sorted out, except for one thing.  I want to be able to show a message on the same page, below the submit button, after I click it, and I'm not sure where to go with this.  This is my code right here:

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <title>
      Audiophile Poll - M100s or Mad Dogs v3.2?
    </title>
    <script>
      function validate[] {
        var radioError = checkRadio();

        if (radioError) {
          document.frmOne.submit();
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      function checkRadio() {
        var headphone = "";
        var len = document.frmOne.headphone.length;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          if (document.frmOne.headphone[i].checked) {
            headphone = document.frmOne.headphone[i].value;
            break;
          }
        }

        if headphone == "") {
          document.getElementById("radio_error"). innerHTML = "You do not have a choice selected.  Please select a choice.";
          return false;
        }
        else {
          document.getElementByID("radio_error"). innerHTNL = "":
          return true;
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: #292E37;
      }
      h1{
        width: 100%;
        color: #800000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New";
        font-size: 40px;
        text-weight: bold;
      }
      .heading{
        color: #808080;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 5px;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .body{
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      .image{
        float: left;
      }
      .paragraph{
        color: #808080;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 60%;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      V-MODA M-100 vs. MrSpeakers Mad Dog
    </h1>
    <div id="box1">
      <div class="heading">
        V-MODA M-100
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://www.acgears.com/images/m_100_shadow_laying_case_square_web.jpg" height="300px" width="300px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
          <b>MSRP:</b> $310<br />
          <b>Frequency Response:</b> <a href="http://www.innerfidelity.com/images/VModaM100.pdf">See here</a> <br />
          <b>Manufacturer:</b> <a href="http://v-moda.com/">V-MODA</a> <br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="box2">
      <div class="heading">
        MrSpeakers Mad Dogs v3.2
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://cdn.head-fi.org/0/05/300x300px-LS-0512aba0_1125220115_maddog.jpeg" height="300px" width="300px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
          <b>MSRP:</b> $299.99 (3.5 mm), $339.99 (universal, no XLR cable incl.), $399.99 (balanced XLR only)<br />
          <b>Frequency Response:</b> <a href="https://www.mrspeakers.com/image/data/mrspeakers/LCD2_DP_AP.png">See here</a> (MDs are red/blue)<br />
          <b>Manufacturer:</b> <a href="https://www.mrspeakers.com/">MrSpeakers</a> <br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form name="frmOne" action="" method="post">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <b>Which would YOU choose to buy?</b> <br />
        <input type="Radio" name="headphone" value="M-100">V-MODA M-100 <br />
<       <input type="Radio" name="headphone" value="MD">MrSpeakers Mad Dog v3.2 <br />
        <span style=color:red id="radio_error"></span>
        <input type="button" value="  Submit  " onClick="validate()">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6s7u/) here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you have syntax error in your code, check console.

Comment: ...Console?  I'm running this off plain HTML.  I don't use a Javascript console.  I just found code I probably could utilize and did some tinkering with it.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) console

Comment: NVM, found an online console.

...Seriously, this is almost as good as Linux's g++ error listings, which is a good thing since I'm learning on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had syntax errors in your scripting code. I have fixed in following fiddle. Replace your JS with the following.

```
  function validate() {
    var radioError = checkRadio();

    if (radioError) {
      document.frmOne.submit();
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  function checkRadio() {
    var headphone = "";
    var len = document.frmOne.headphone.length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (document.frmOne.headphone[i].checked) {
        headphone = document.frmOne.headphone[i].value;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (headphone == "") {
      document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "You do not have a choice selected.  Please select a choice.";
      return false;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("radio_error").innerHTML = "";
      return true;
    }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E6s7u/4/